# Apex Testing Failing at 23%

Tags: apex, unit-test

My test is failing at 23%, an entire section is failing for some reason and I am not sure why, can someone help? The portion that fails is everything from public PageReference send() and below. Here is my class code (Highlighting the portion that failed):

```
public without sharing class requnl_class
{
    private ApexPages.StandardController standardController;
    public String recId {get; set;}


    public requnl_class(ApexPages.StandardController standardController)
    {
        recId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');  
    }


    public PageReference send() {

        Messaging.singleEmailmessage email = new Messaging.singleEmailmessage();

        patient_chart__c PatientId = [SELECT Id FROM patient_chart__c WHERE ID =:recid Limit 1]; 

        List<string>sendTo = new List<String>();

        sendTo.add('support@restorehair.com'); 

        email.setToAddresses(sendTo);

        email.setSubject('Please unlock this patient chart.'); 

        email.setHtmlBody('Please unlock cs28.salesforce.com/'+PatientId.Id);

        Messaging.sendEmailResult[] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.singleEmailmessage[] {email});

        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is my testing code:

```
@istest (seeAllData = True) private class requnl_class_test  {

    @isTest static void requnl_class_test () {
        Patient_Details__c client = new Patient_Details__c(
            Patient_name__c='Donkey Kong',
            Email_Address__c='tom@tom.com',
            Phone_number3__c='2012012233'
        );
        insert client;
        Patient_chart__c chart= new Patient_chart__c (
            RESTORE_Client__c=client.Id,
            name='sard'
        );
        insert chart;

        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',chart.id);
        ApexPages.StandardController stdController = new ApexPages.StandardController(chart);

        requnl_class consext  = new requnl_class(stdController);

        PageReference pageRef = Page.Request_Unlock;

        test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

    }
}
```

Comment: Using `seeAllData=true` is usually a bad sign. Best practice is to create all of the data you need to use for the test in the test class itself. Unit testing is a very common topic here, so I'd recommend taking a look through the [tag:canonical-qa] tag to see if that helps answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling send() method in test class. Add following line to your test.

```
consext.send();
```

On the other hand, your test is doesn't look good, first of all you are using seeAllData=true, which is not a good practice.

Additionally it is better to remove email address of your client from code.

Comment: Thanks for you input, I will eliminate the seealldata, when I added the .send(); it seemed to not like that and it gave me 14 errors in the dev console, not sure why. Do you have any insight?

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized I had to add that line independently of my other lines of code, it worked after that.